# how to get integers from edittext and multiply them using kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-7.0-nougat

I cannot seem to figure out how to take the value entered into a textedit, convert to srting/int and then multiply them together. I have 3 inputs i want multiplied with a button click and then displayed in the text of a text view.
as a exercise to see if my button works and changing the text view was working, i used append and it works, I just cant get them to multiply.

looking over some of these threads I still cannot seem to make it work:

[Android - How to get text from edittext and calculate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983086/android-how-to-get-text-from-edittext-and-calculate-them)

[Android - How to get text from edittext and calculate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983086/android-how-to-get-text-from-edittext-and-calculate-them)

[Convert EditText input to integer and multiply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095983/convert-edittext-input-to-integer-and-multiply)

## Fragment Code in Koltin (with what i need missing)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.MultiplyExample.*

class MultiplyExample : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView( inflater: LayoutInflater, container: 
ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_retention, container, false) }
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
override fun onClick(v: View) {

val a: Int = length.text.toString().toInt()
val b: Int = flight.text.toString().toInt()
val c: Int = rotation.text.toString().toInt()
```

## Working as append with stringbuilder#

```
val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append(a).append(b).append(c)
d.text = sb
```

## XML is the same for a,b,c

```
<EditText
        android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to reference the widgets in the fragments without `findViewById`.

In your method `onCreateView` put some code like so before the return statement.

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_retention, container, false)

val a: Int = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.length).text.toString().toInt()
val b: Int = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.flight).text.toString().toInt()
val c: Int = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rotation).text.toString().toInt()

val multiplication = a * b * c

return view
```

Comment: that method worked like a charm, however they are <EditText> fields and not <TextView> but the concept of writing out the full statement worked. Android Studio was suggesting it the was i had it so i assumed it was good.   Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Android Studio doesn't seem to know that the suggestions don't work in the fragments, which is annoying. It took me a while to figure out too.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in fragment

```
 myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

        myView.multiply_btn.setOnClickListener { myView ->
            val number1 =number_et1.text.toString().toInt()
            val number2 = number_et2.text.toString().toInt()
            val number3 = number_et3.text.toString().toInt()

            val multiply: Int = number1 * number2 * number3
            answer_tv.text = "Multiply is: " + multiply
        }
        return myView
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: thanks, but this is actually what i was trying, the way you have it will not build because it needs Int after number ( val number1: Int = ), and after the suggestion from Taimoor Ahmad in their answer, it needs the findViewById in order to find the actual field and not the widget.

Answer (score 0):

First convert textField data into string by using toString() and then convert the resultant data into integer or double by using this code:

```
btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double num1,num2,res;
                num1 = Double.valueOf(editFirst.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.valueOf(editSecond.getText().toString());
                res = num1 - num2;
                result.setText(""+res);
```